# Code not cycling through sheets

Tags: vba, excel

My Workbook has several sheets named Detail1, Detail2, Detail3, and so on. I´d like to color the sheet according to the content of cell B15. However the code is only coloring sheet Detail1 and not cycling through the other sheets. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Sub Color_by_cell_value()
Dim X As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "Detail*" Then
            X = Range("B15").Value
            Select Case X
            Case Is = "no"
                Range("A1:AZ100").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                End With
                Range("B15").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = 5296274
                End With
            Case Is = "yes"
                Range("A1:AZ100").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
                End With
                Range("B15").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = 255
                End With
            Case Is = "yes/no"
                Range("A1:AZ100").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                End With
                Range("B15").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Color = 65535
                End With
            End Select
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of ways to edit this code and make it more efficient, but to answer your question. `ws.select` would be required after line.If `ws.Name Like "Detail*" Then`

```
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Detail*" Then
        ws.Select
        X = Range("B15").Value
        Select Case X
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thank you very much, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ws.Activate`:

```
Sub Color_by_cell_value()
Dim X As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like "Detail*" Then

        ws.Activate
        X = Range("B15").Value

        Select Case X
        Case Is = "no"
            Range("A1:AZ100").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            End With
            Range("B15").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 5296274
            End With
        Case Is = "yes"
            Range("A1:AZ100").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            End With
            Range("B15").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 255
            End With
        Case Is = "yes/no"
            Range("A1:AZ100").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            End With
            Range("B15").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 65535
            End With
        End Select
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note I also set the [`Application.ScreenUpdating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) to `False` as a good custom.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I´ll deactivate screen update now that it works!